# writing unsigned data to binary file in C++

Tags: c++, io, binary

I am trying to write the sequence

56 4F 4C 03

as binary (unsigned char) into a file.

In ASCII, This should spell out "VOL ", where according to my hex editor, and the 4th character corresponding to the byte '03' is a non-displaying character.

The following writes "VOL" correctly but I don't know how to write the raw unsigned '03' data as it is a non-displaying character. How can I do this? Should I code in identifiers like 0x03 or is there a cleaner way?

```
int main()
{
    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open ("data.vol", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
    std::string str = "VOL";

    std::string::size_type sz = str.size();
    // when i leave this line out, it writes to string?
    outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sz), sizeof(std::string::size_type));
    outfile.write(str.data(),sz);

    std::string m_version_identifier = "3";
    outfile.write((char*)&m_version_identifier.data()[0],m_version_identifier.size());

    outfile.close();

    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for character `'\03'` or string `"VOL\03"`.

Writing byte itself may be cleaner approach:

```
int version = 3;
outfile.write(&version,1);
```